# Why did the Savoraim only emend certain parts of the Talmud?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, mesorah-tradition, savoraim

I remember learning that [Savoraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoraim) added certain parts to the Talmud- ex: the beginning of Kiddushin ([2a-3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.2a.3-3a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) & parts of Bava Metzia.
(feel free to add additional examples)

Any idea why they specifically chose to author specific parts in specific *Masechtas*?

Comment: Are you asking specifically why traditional sources only identify specific areas of Savoraic authorship/editorship? Because various academic scholars do in fact assert that large portions of the Talmud are actually Savoraic.

Comment: @Alex oh interesting- happen to have a link to a place that lists all the parts of the Talmud that are Savoraic?

Comment: No, but you may want to see the "Impact" and "Controversy" sections [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weiss_Halivni) for a very brief introduction to this approach.

Comment: I suspect, that the Rishonim (generation) were those who included the Svoraim into the Gemmarah. This is how our book redaction works. Same is true for the Mishnah. The Gemmarah presents a slightly different version of the Mishnayot than the Mishnah itself.